# Why are my variables not being correctly defined in my if...else statement?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

In the code below, I've defined a function called checkPassword(), which takes in a single argument, passwordCorrect, which will be either true or false.

I've also defined two variables, accessGranted and message, which currently have no values (they're undefined) and will be overwritten and defined by your if statement if you've written it correctly.

I need to write an if statement inside the function that updates the two variables, accessGranted (a boolean), and message (a string), to meet the requirements below

Requirements:
1) If passwordCorrect is true, accessGranted should have a value of true and message should have a value of 'Welcome to the admin panel!'
2) In any other case, accessGranted should have a value of false and message should have a value of 'Wrong password.'

```js
var accessGranted;
var message;

function checkPassword(passwordCorrect) {
  if passwordCorrect == true {
    accessGranted = true;
    message = "Welcome to the admin panel!";
  }

  else {
    accessGranted = false;
    message = "Wrong password."

  }

}

console.log('Access Granted:', accessGranted);
console.log('Message:', message);
```

Comment: First thing to do would be to check  the console for errors.

Comment: It's surprising that the errors were missed since the whole point of program is to log something to the console.

Comment: Voting to close because the problem was caused by a typo. Missing `(` and `)`. Please reread the syntax for `if` statements.

Comment: Also **you have to call functions** before they do anything

Comment: Why are you declaring variables outside of a function? You should be declaring them within the function, or returning an object from the function. Using global variables is a very bad habit to get into, so kick it now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call the function and fix your syntax error. If statements need parentheses in javascript.

```
let accessGranted;
let message;

function checkPassword(passwordCorrect) {
  if (passwordCorrect) {
    accessGranted = true;
    message = "Welcome to the admin panel!";
  }

  else {
    accessGranted = false;
    message = "Wrong password."

  }

}

checkPassword(true)

console.log('Access Granted:', accessGranted);
console.log('Message:', message);
```